# Sklearn: Output prediction from SVM/RFC are for 1 class

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm using the SVM and RandomForestClassifier from the sklearn toolkit.
I split my data into training and testing, though, my dataset is very imbalanced, 20% of positive and 80% training.

To account for that I used the class_weight property, and set it to balanced.

The resulted probabilities are all set to the dominant class, I get things like [0.8 0.2] for all testing samples.

I'm not sure what is going wrong, but I believe the class_weight is not working properly since undersampling the most common class made the probabilities look normal.

So, any tips on how to solve this? I thought the weights should fix it but its not.

Edit code:

```
skf = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=splits, test_size=0.25,random_state=1)
for train, test in skf.split(X, Y):
  wt=np.zeros(len(Y_train));#weights for imbalanced
    for i in range(0,len(Y_train),+1):
                    if Y_train[i]==1:
                        wt[i]=0.20#less data for positive class
                    else:
                        wt[i]=0.05 
clf = svm.SVC(C=100,kernel='rbf',gamma=0.001,probability=True)
clf.fit(X_train,Y_train.ravel(),sample_weight=wt)
probas = clf.predict_proba(Xtest)[:, 1]
```

I Also tried:

```
w='balanced'
    clf = svm.SVC(C=100,kernel='rbf',gamma=0.001,class_weight=w,probability=True)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Edited and added